# Open BMP to an array using Visual C++ and OpenCV 2.1

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, opencv

I open an image with:

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("C:\\foo.bmp",-1);
```

And now I want to put this image to three 2D arrays.

```
unsigned int r[img->width][img->height];
unsigned int g[img->width][img->height];
unsigned int b[img->width][img->height];
```

This doesn't work, because I get "expression must have a constant value". Why isn't it constant?

How do I get each color channel separated to each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvSplit` splits an image into single-channel arrays ([documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsplit#split)).

Comment: Thank you! This helps me for the first. I also use opencv datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Static array allocation like that requires the dimensions to be a *compile time* constant. The parameters `img->width` and `img->height` aren't known until run time (the compiler cannot know the size of foo.bmp), so you can't allocate an array statically like that.

It's better to use `cvSplit` like SSteve mentions anyway.